# android sax parser shows only first line in TextView

Tags: android, xml, parsing, textview, sax

i am working on my first project with android and java
and have very little experience. 
i have a radio player (start and stop button that activates a service)
and 
some data from a xml file   like artist title and album loaded in a textview
i use a timer so that the gui updates with the song played

this all works 
only when the lyrics are loaded in the textview it only shows the first line of the xml tag `<LYRIC>`

this is my main activity:

```
extends  Activity implements OnClickListener{

     private static final String TAG = "ServicesDemo";
     public String myimageURL;
     private EditText Lyrics;
    private ImageView AlbumPic;
    private Button play,  stop;
    private TextView Artist, Song, Album, News, Lyric;
    private UpdateTimeTask m_updateTime;
    private Handler m_handler;
    Parser data;
    /** The delay in milliseconds between updates. */
    private final int DELAY = 20000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Artist =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvArtist);
        Song  =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSongTitle);
        Album =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAlbum);
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        Lyrics = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvLyrics);
        News = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAnouncement);
        AlbumPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.AlbumPic);



        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);



        m_updateTime = new UpdateTimeTask();

        m_handler = new Handler();
        m_handler.post(m_updateTime);
    }

    private class UpdateTimeTask implements Runnable {
        public void run() {


            try {

                SAXParserFactory saxPF = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser saxP = saxPF.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xmlR = saxP.getXMLReader();


                URL url = new URL("http://www.mysite.com/AndroidTest.php"); 
                XMLHandler myXMLHandler = new XMLHandler();
                xmlR.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
                xmlR.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            data = XMLHandler.data;



            for (int i = 0; i < data.getTitle().size(); i++) {

           Lyrics.setText(data.getLyric().get(i));
                 myimageURL = data.getPic().get(i);

            Song.setText("Title = "+data.getTitle().get(i));


            Artist.setText("Artist = "+data.getArtist().get(i));


            Album.setText("Album = "+data.getAlbum().get(i)); 






 }

 downloadFile(myimageURL );

}

Bitmap bmImg;
void downloadFile(String fileUrl) {
 URL myFileUrl = null;
 try {
    myFileUrl = new URL(fileUrl);
 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
 try {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl
          .openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

    bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    AlbumPic.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
 } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
 m_handler.postDelayed(m_updateTime, DELAY);
 AlbumPic.clearAnimation();
}

}
```

**my xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CATALOG>
<CD>
<LYRIC>Stop that train: I'm leavin' - today!
Stop that train: I'm leavin' - anyway!
Stop that train: I'm leavin'. and I said:
It won't be too long whether I'm right or wrong;
I said, it won't be too long whether I'm right or wrong.

All my good life I've been a lonely man,
Teachin' my people who don't understand;
And even though I tried my best,
I still can't find no happiness.

So I got to say:
Stop that train: I'm leavin' - oh, baby now!
Stop that train: I'm leavin' - don't care what you say!
Stop that train: I'm leavin'. and I said:
It won't be too long whether I'm right or wrong;
Said, it won't be too long whether I'm right or wrong.

Some goin' east; and-a some goin' west,
Some stand aside to try their best.
Some livin' big, but the most is livin' small:
They just can't even find no food at all.

I mean, stop it:
Stop that train: I'm leavin' - leavin', mm-hmm.
Stop that train: I'm leavin' - I don't mind!
Stop that train: I'm leavin'. and I said:
It won't be too long whether I'm right or wrong;
I said it won't be too long whether I'm right or wrong.

Stop that train: I'm leavin' - leavin'!
Stop that train: I'm leavin' - can't take it!
Stop that train: I'm leavin' - got to be better!
It won't be too long whether I'm right or wrong;
I said it won't be too long whether I'm right or wrong.</LYRIC>
<ARTIST>Bob Marley</ARTIST>
<TITLE>Stop That Train</TITLE>
<ALBUM>Talkin blues</ALBUM>
<PIC>http://www.mysite.com/Android/Radio/AlbumCovers/Bob-Marley-Talkin-blues.jpg</PIC>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

i also tried to load the lyrics using edittext but there it also only show the first line of the `<LYRIC>` tag

can someone give some advice how to show the whole text in the textview

thanks

my xmlhandler

```
public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    String elementValue = null;
    Boolean elementOn = false;
    public static Parser data = null;

    public static Parser getXMLData() {
        return data;
    }

    public static void setXMLData(Parser data) {
        XMLHandler.data = data;
    }

    /** 
     * This will be called when the tags of the XML starts.
     **/
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        elementOn = true;

        if (localName.equals("CATALOG"))
        {
            data = new Parser();
        } else if (localName.equals("CD")) {
            /** 
             * We can get the values of attributes for eg. if the CD tag had an attribute( <CD attr= "band">Akon</CD> ) 
             * we can get the value "band". Below is an example of how to achieve this.
             * 
             * String attributeValue = attributes.getValue("attr");
             * data.setAttribute(attributeValue);
             * 
             * */
        }
    }

    /** 
     * This will be called when the tags of the XML end.
     **/
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

        elementOn = false;

        /** 
         * Sets the values after retrieving the values from the XML tags
         * */ 
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
            data.setTitle(elementValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("artist"))
            data.setArtist(elementValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("album"))
            data.setAlbum(elementValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("lyric"))
            data.setLyric(elementValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pic"))
            data.setPic(elementValue);


    }

    /** 
     * This is called to get the tags value
     **/
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {

        if (elementOn) {
            elementValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            elementOn = false;
        }

    }

    public void post(Runnable mUpdate) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void removeCallbacks(Runnable sendUpdatesToUI) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void postDelayed(Runnable runnable, int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you to check you XMLHandler object. I suspect you have something wrong there.

If you can show us your XMLHandler class that would be better to help you.

**EDIT:**

I have made some changes to your handler. I think you might have a problem when you read the element value. Use a CharArrayWriter instead (I've resolve an identical problem with that).
And I think you doesn't need the 'elementOn' too. If its a non necessary variable just don't use it.
Make sure you have too a multine TextView defined on your XML layout.
Hope it works :-)

```
public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private static final String TAG = "XMLHandler";
    private String elementValue = null;
    public static Parser data = null;

    /** The contents. */
    private CharArrayWriter contents = new CharArrayWriter();

    public static Parser getXMLData() {
        return data;
    }

    public static void setXMLData(Parser data) {
        XMLHandler.data = data;
    }

    /** 
     * This will be called when the tags of the XML starts.
     **/
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        /**It´s a good practice to reset the CharArrayWriter when you start any element.*/
        contents.reset();

        if (localName.equals("CATALOG"))
        {
            data = new Parser();
        } else if (localName.equals("CD")) {
            /** 
             * We can get the values of attributes for eg. if the CD tag had an attribute( <CD attr= "band">Akon</CD> ) 
             * we can get the value "band". Below is an example of how to achieve this.
             * 
             * String attributeValue = attributes.getValue("attr");
             * data.setAttribute(attributeValue);
             * 
             * */
        }
    }

    /** 
     * This will be called when the tags of the XML end.
     **/
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        /** 
         * Sets the values after retrieving the values from the XML tags
         * */ 
         String elementValue = contents.toString().trim();

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
            data.setTitle(elementValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("artist"))
            data.setArtist(elementValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("album"))
            data.setAlbum(elementValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("lyric"))
            data.setLyric(elementValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pic"))
            data.setPic(elementValue);
    }

    /** 
     * This is called to get the tags value
     **/
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            contents.write(ch, start, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        Log.i(TAG, "Catalog parse finalized with success.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're very welcome. Let me know your progress...
Show me your code to help you with de bug.

Comment: i edited my post above and included the code for the xmlhandler i only understand half of what is going on maybe it has to do something with my xml file itself. i first had problems to get the pictures loaded when the name of the jpg file started with "as_" i dynamically changed all  jpg file names and that problem was solved but now problems with the lyrics

Comment: Yes! it Worked! thanks a lot you really helped me, not only the whole lyrics are showing but my app runs smoother also :-) Thank you Yugidroid for your time.

Comment: @user1505173, you're very welcome. I'm glad to help you.
Can you accept the answer, please? :)